# How to set navbar item as active when user selects it?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, master-pages, navbar

I am a new ASP.NET Web Forms developer and trying to use Twitter Bootstrap with the Master Page. I am struggling with setting navbar item as active when user selects it. I created my simple master page by following [this tutorial](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/do%2a%2at-net/bootstrap-with-asp-net) about how to use Twitter Bootstrap with ASP.NET.

Here's the code of my master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>Hello... My First Website with Twitter Bootstrap</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li class="nav-header">Navigation</li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">ASP.NET</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Default2.aspx">Java</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">VB.Net</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">C#</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </div>
                <div class="span9">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I added this script to **the Head** in order to fix issue with the menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var substr = url.split('/');
        var urlaspx = substr[substr.length - 1];
        $('.nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.nav li a').each(function () {
            if (this.href.indexOf(urlaspx) >= 0) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, nothing has been changed. When I selected any item from the navigation bar, the active class has not been added to the new selected item and I don't know why. **Could you please help me in fixing this issue.?**

Comment: Check this out: https://gist.github.com/josephwambura/ef97b44c309226301847d3e09e0e2562#how-to-set-navbar-item-as-active-when-user-selects-it-in-c

Answer (score 26):

Use this:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="/Default.aspx">Default</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Clients.aspx">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="/_display/">Display</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location;
        $('.navbar .nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.navbar .nav li a').each(function () {
            if (this.href == url) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yUdZx/3/

And, in the "href" use "Page.ResolveUrl"

```
<a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Clients.aspx") %>">Clients</a>
```

It's better...

Comment: This worked perfect without having to resort to using local storage!

Answer (score 4):

Actually Reynaldo, almost had it... 
At least for me, this works pretty good, on activing the current option and deactiving the previous one, based on his example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location;                
    $('ul.nav li a').each(function () {
         if (this.href == url) {
              $("ul.nav li").each(function () {
                   if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                        $(this).removeClass("active");
                   }
              });
              $(this).parent().addClass('active');
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For those as myself that prefer server-side implementations, transform your **li** tags of interest to **runat="server"** on the Master.Page file. The code in question will look something similar to this:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item" runat="server" id="tabHome" >
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" runat="server" id="tabContact">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" runat="server">Hello, <asp:LoginName runat="server" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Then in the code behind of the Master page - Site.Master.vb or Site.Master.cs, depending on the language used - add the following in the Page Load event:

**VB.Net implementation:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim thisURL As String = Request.Url.Segments(Request.Url.Segments.Count - 1)

    Select Case thisURL
        Case "Default", "default.aspx"  
            tabContact.Attributes.Remove("active")
            tabHome.Attributes.Add("class", "active")
        Case "Contact"
            tabHome.Attributes.Remove("active")
            tabContact.Attributes.Add("class", "active")
    End Select
End Sub
```

**C# implementation:**

```
Protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string thisURL = Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1];

    switch (thisURL)
    {
        Case "Default":
        Case "default.aspx": 
            {
                tabContact.Attributes.Remove("active");
                tabHome.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                break;
            }

        Case "Contact" : 
            {
                tabHome.Attributes.Remove("active");
                tabContact.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Since is "Default.aspx" the page that is supposed to be opened initially, the "Home" menu item will be highlighted as soon the user enters the website. An example is displayed below:

[image]

For the sake of simplicity, only two navbar items were used in the example, but the same logic could be implemented if more are required.

I hope can be of help.

Comment: This C# solution worked for me but this line of code: "string thisURL = Request.Url.Segments(Request.Url.Segments.Count - 1); is slightly incorrect, it needs square brackets instead of parenthesis and Length property (not Count)like this: "string thisURL = Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1];" It tripped me up for a bit. Found the correct syntax explained here by masoud Cheragee:  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189062/does-a-masterpage-know-what-page-is-being-displayed

Comment: @Doreen, thanks! I have updated the code in the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've placed this in each one of my content pages, changing the id of the nav item for each page (this uses JQuery selectors). So for this to work for you you'll need to give your list items an Id.  I don't add the "active" class to the master page because all we need to do is highlight the appropriate one when the content loads.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id$=yourNavItemId]").addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

Note: if you're using ASP.NET controls instead of list items inside of your nav bar, they might be getting prefixed at runtime causing your javascript not to find the Id you think you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

following code works if I have subpages:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.navbar .nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');

        var url = window.location.toString();
        var u = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/")).toString();

        $('.navbar .nav li a').each(function () {

            var hr = this.href.substring(0, this.href.lastIndexOf('/')).toString();

            if ((u == hr) || (u.indexOf(hr) > -1))
            {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                return false;
            }
        });
        // Deactivation to manually add items you have with href = "#" example:
        $('#liSalir').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **navigation** bar with **dropdown-menu** then put below script at end of your master page(*before body closing tag*):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location;
    $('ul.nav li a').each(function () {
        if (this.href == url) {
            $("ul.nav li").each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                }
            });
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This completely worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but use

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var url = window.location;
    $('ul.nav li a').each(function () {
        if (this.href == url) {
            $("ul.nav li").each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                }
            });
            $(this).parents().addClass('active');
        }

    });

});
```

Since you also wants to active the all the parents.

Answer (score 0):

```
var windowUrl = window.location.href.toLowerCase();
//var windowUrl = window.location.href.toLowerCase().split('.')[0];
setTimeout(function () {
    var windowUrl = window.location.href.toLowerCase();
    $('#nav li').removeClass('active');
    $('#nav li').each(function (index) {
        pageUrl = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        if (windowUrl.indexOf(pageUrl) > -1) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample which full fill your requirement you need to modify the code according to your need.
Use this jquery on master page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=submenu]').addClass('sub-menu open');
            $('[id*=Master_Pages]').attr("aria-expanded", true);

            $('.subMenus').click(function () {
                localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('id'));
            });
        });
        function pageLoad() {
            var isActiveLink = false;
            $.each($('.subMenus'), function () {
                if ($(this).attr('id') == localStorage.getItem('lastTab')) {
                    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
                    localStorage.removeItem('lastTab');
                    isActiveLink = true;
                }
                else {
                    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                }
            });
            if (!isActiveLink) {
                $('[id*=Master_Designation]').closest('li').addClass('active');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: it would be better if you add the explanation of your solution, hence we can edit according to our requirements

Answer (score 0):

Some helpful article for .Net guys

https://gist.github.com/josephwambura/ef97b44c309226301847d3e09e0e2562?permalink_comment_id=4381643#gistcomment-4381643