# How get url of current page that has a master page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a few child pages, utilizing a master page in the default directory. These children pages are in different subdirectories. How do I get the url of the current page? NOT the master page, but the child page?

Comment: I think you will have to clarify this - when one of the child pages is the current page, then the URL is the URL of the child page. So presumably you don't mean that, but what *do* you mean?

Comment: This is answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189062/does-a-masterpage-know-what-page-is-being-displayed

Comment: Your question is really confusing. Please post the code what you have tried. ***FYI:*** please do not tag a bunch of unrelated tags to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the good old days we used `ServerVariables` a lot, and they still handy, for example you can get your page from the URL Path with `Request.ServerVariable("PATH_INFO")`

this will give you `/sessions.aspx` for a `http://domain.com/session.aspx`

or, if you want the server path, you can use `Request.ServerVariable("PATH_TRANSLATED")` and that will return something like `D:\websites\wwwroot\sessions.aspx`

---

Nowdays we tend to use the [`HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpRequest_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) object for such values, and one of them is the [`HttpRequest.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will also have a lot of information that you can use.

You can [**see my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932773/28004) to know more about it, but maily, you can see this image:

[image]